# repositoryItem reader org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property 'MANIFBURENREGMANIF' found for type 'ArticleManifeste'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

*org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property 'MANIFBURENREGMANIF' found for type 'ArticleManifeste'*

**This is my code **

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ARTICLEMANIFESTE")
@Data
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level= AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@IdClass(ArticleManifesteKey.class)

public class ArticleManifeste implements Serializable {
 static final long serialVersionUID = -7273917648454868311L;

 @Id
 @Size(max = 3)
 @NotNull
 @Column(name="MANIFBURENREGMANIF", length=3, nullable = false)
 String manifBureauEngManif;

@Id
 @Size(max = 4)
 @NotNull
 @Column(name="MANIFANNEEENREGMANIF", length=4, nullable = false)
 String manifAnneeEngManif;
 ...........
 }
```

Entity key

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@FieldDefaults(level= AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class ArticleManifesteKey implements Serializable {

   static final long serialVersionUID = 203621482537663708L;


   @Id
   @Column(name="MANIFBURENREGMANIF", length=3, nullable=false)
   String manifBureauEngManif;

   /**
    * Implementation field for persistent attribute: manifanneeengmanif
    */
   @Id
   @Column(name="MANIFANNEEENREGMANIF", length=4, nullable=false)
   String manifAnneeEngManif;

 ........
}
```

Some error when use CrudRepository

```
@Repository
 public interface ArticleManifesteRepository  extends PagingAndSortingRepository<ArticleManifeste, String> {
     @Override
     Page<ArticleManifeste> findAll(Pageable pageable);
 }
```

Also when i use the crudRepo and here change return type to list

```
@Service
public interface ArticleManifesteService {
    public Iterable<ArticleManifeste> findAll();
}
```

Implementation of service

```
@Service
public class ArticleManifesteServiceImp implements ArticleManifesteService {

    @Autowired
    ArticleManifesteRepository articleManifesteRepository;


    @Override
    public Iterable<ArticleManifeste> findAll() {
        return articleManifesteRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

I'm using this reader in a batch configuration, I'm trying to read data from the Article Manifest table.

```
  @Bean
    public RepositoryItemReader<ArticleManifeste> reader() {
        RepositoryItemReader<ArticleManifeste> reader = new RepositoryItemReader<>();
        reader.setRepository(articleManifesteRepository);
        reader.setMethodName("findAll");
        List<Object> queryMethodArguments = new ArrayList<>();
        reader.setPageSize(100);
        Map<String, Direction> sorts = new HashMap<>();
        sorts.put("MANIFBURENREGMANIF", Direction.ASC);
        reader.setSort(sorts);
        return reader;
    }
```

Comment: Please check the spelling for "MANIFBURENREGMANIF" and check if such property exists in your entity class.

Comment: property exists in entity, problem that when I use id works but when I use composite id doesn't

Comment: Please post the full stack trace to be able to help you efficiently. Providing a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue is the best way to get the help you need.